Finding radical of an ideal in polynomial ring in $4$ indeterminates
Let $K$ be a field and $R = K [a,b,c,d]$ a polynomial ring where $a, b, c, d$ are indeterminates.  Let
$$A =\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  c & d
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}
  a^2+bc & ab+bd\\ 
  ac+cd & bc+d^2
\end{pmatrix}$$ and define a ideal $I$ of $R$ such that
$I =  \langle a^2+bc, ab+bd, ac+cd, bc+d^2 \rangle.$
Prove that $\mathrm{rad}(I) = \langle \det A, \operatorname{trace} A \rangle$.
I am a new learner of commutative algebra. I know definition of the radical of an ideal.
Here I was thinking of using that for every $ 2 \times 2 $ matrix $A$ we can write $$\operatorname{ch}_A (x) = x^2 - (\operatorname{trace} A) x  + (\det A),$$ but then I got stuck.

Purely algebraic solution:
We first prove that $\text{det}(A)$ and $\text{tr}(A)$ are contained in $\sqrt{I} = \text{rad}(I)$. To see this I first claim that $\text{det}(A)^2 \in \sqrt{I}$.
Indeed we have
\begin{align}
\text{det}(A)^2 &= a^2d^2 + b^2c^2 - 2abcd = \\
&= d^2(a^2 + bc) - cd(ab + bd) + a^2(bc + d^2) - ab(ac+cd) \in I
\end{align}
Next I claim that $\text{tr}(A)^2 \in \sqrt{I}$. To see this we use the Newton Identities (applied to the characteristic polynomial of $A$) telling us that
\begin{equation}
\text{tr}(A)^2 = 2\text{det}(A) - \text{tr}(A^2) \in \sqrt{I}.
\end{equation}
Note that $\text{tr}(A^2)$ is trivially contained in $I \subseteq \sqrt{I}$. In particular we get $J := \langle \text{tr}(A), \text{det}(A) \rangle \subseteq \sqrt{I}$. Furthermore you can verify that the generators of $I$ can be expressed via the elements $\text{det}(A)$ and $\text{tr}(A)$, so $I \subseteq J$.
What is then left to prove is that the ideal $J$ is indeed radical, since then we have
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{I} \subseteq \sqrt{J} = J \subseteq \sqrt{\sqrt{I}} = \sqrt{I}
\end{equation}
Equivalently we may prove that $R/J$ is reduced (i.e. there are no nilpotent elements). To see this first note that $\text{tr}(A) = a + d$ lets us substitute $d$ with $-a$. Thus we have
\begin{equation}
R/J \cong K[a,b,c]/(-a^2-bc)
\end{equation}
which is even an integral domain.

Here is an idea for what is happening 'behind the scenes':
Your ideal $I$ describes the common zero set of the polynomial entries of $A^2$. In other words, it describes the locus of points in $K^4$ such that $A^2 = 0$. This means that $A$ was nilpotent, which happens if and only if $A$ has eigenvalues only 0.
Now you can use your formula for the characteristic polynomial of $A$ which gives you
\begin{equation}
x^2 - \text{tr}(A)x + \det(A)
\end{equation}
and you want this polynomial to be $x^2$. Thus the conditions $\det(A) = 0$ and $\text{tr}(A) = 0$.

Please use $\langle I\rangle to produce $\langle I \rangle$ instead of $<I>$ for $$. I've made the change for you this time.

We note that
$$(ad-bc)^2=d^2(a^2+bc)+bc(bc+d^2)-2bd(ac+cd)\in I,$$
so $ad-bc\in \sqrt I$. Next, we have
$$(a+d)^2=(a^2+bc)+(d^2+bc)+2(ad-bc)\in\sqrt I,$$
so $a+d\in \sqrt{\sqrt I}=\sqrt I$. Thus we see that the prime ideal $P=(ad-bc,a+d)$ is contained in $\sqrt I$.
Now let $Q$ be a minimal prime over $I$. By above, we know that some powers of $ad-bc$ and $a+d$ are in $I$, so by the primeness of $Q$, we get $ad-bc,a+d\in Q$, i.e., $P\subseteq Q$. By the minimality of $Q$, we must have $P=Q$. So we get $I\subseteq P$. Taking radical on both sides, we get $\sqrt I\subseteq P$.
